# How to Run Hippo CMS

Tags: java, maven, svn, hippocms

I've got Hippo CMS source code with SVN. Fortunately it is maven based and it gets all dependencies automatically.
I've installed it with Maven successfully.and both site.war and CMS.war and two other jar file were built.

But I don't know how to run it. The documentation says to run it using `mvn -P cargo.run`.

I've done that and everything seems OK, when I try to browse to `localhost:8080/cms` or `localhost:8080/site` nothing appears.

Can somebody help if I must do some other thing? Or  if I did something wrong?

Comment: w.r.t. the off topic flag: as far as I can tell this is about using Hippo CMS, on localhost, as developer. In my opinion it does belong to Stack Overflow and it is not off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to do a SVN checkout.

You can create a startup project with a maven archetype, type:

```
mvn archetype:generate 
-DarchetypeRepository=http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.onehippo.cms7 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=hippo-archetype-website 
-DarchetypeVersion=1.07.06
```

then you can

```
mvn install
```

and to start your project

```
mvn -P cargo.run
```

or to avoid to start from a fresh repository everytime

```
mvn -P cargo.run -Drepo.path=/home/usr/myrepo
```

This is all explained here:
http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/trails/developer-trail/hippo-baby-steps.html

Comment: tnx for ur answer, I did as you said , but it failed due to the defined artifact is not archetype , what is wrong?

Comment: the mvn command should be on a single line without the \
like this: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeRepository=http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.onehippo.cms7 -DarchetypeArtifactId=hippo-archetype-website -DarchetypeVersion=1.07.06

Comment: I did the same ,but still have problem. does it depends on any thing else ? my maven version is 2.2 and i also tried with maven 3 , any depending thing else ?

Comment: i think problem is with it version or something like this because 1.07 is very old the newest one is 1.09 with lots of changes , do you have any idea ?

Comment: I was able to generate a project now with version 1.07